# What is the regular expression for International phone number validation in php or zend?

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a zend form where I have a phone number field and have to check for validator.

I have decided to use regular expression for that. I searched google but the results I have is not working.

Can anyone please provide me the regular expression. 
here is my code:

```
 $phone = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('phone');
            $phone->setRequired(true);
            $phone->setLabel('Phone :')
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty', false, array('messages'=>'phone cannot be empty'))
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('regex', false, array('/^[0-9 ]+$/','messages'=>'not a valid phone number'))
            ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(5, 25, 'messages'=>'phone must be 5-25 character'))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gabber , I searched quite a lot but those are not working. That's why I posted the question. The mistake I was doing is that I was not using the '/' at the beginning and end of the expression. Which I have learnt from the answer given by user1559230 .

Thanks for your comment Gabber . I will definitely remember it for the next time.

Comment: Thank you for the polite reply :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^((\+|00)\d{1,3})?\d+$/
```

Try the above expression. hope this helps.

Comment: What's the point of the `\d{1,3}`? I know it matches 1-3 digits, but for any number with at least 3 digits (following the optional `00`), it will match all 3 of them. For example, given `+18005551212`, the `\d{1,3}` matches `180`, which is meaningless. And your regexp rejects numbers with embedded spaces and hyphens; is that your intent?

Answer (score 2):

Please note that phone number is one of the hardest everyday data validations that exist (along with email, that can contain "+" for example or port number in domain). You should understand the implications of using "some" regex. There may be some users (even whole countries) that won't match some regexes. Or users can input numbers, that are not phone numbers even though they match the regex.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

There's been an issue about Zend_Phone to implement E.164. But I was not implemented in the end. The accepted solution (`/^((\+|00)\d{1,3})?\d+$/`) would match even next string as valid phone:

```
+0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: the world is small

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, works for me

```
/^(\+[\d|\-]*)\s([0-9]+)$/
```

or extended version

```
/^(\+[011|999|998|997|996|995|994|993|992|991|990|979|978|977|976|975|974|973|972|971|970|969|968|967|966|965|964|963|962|961|960|899|898|897|896|895|894|893|892|891|890|889|888|887|886|885|884|883|882|881|880|879|878|877|876|875|874|873|872|871|870|859|858|857|856|855|854|853|852|851|850|839|838|837|836|835|834|833|832|831|830|809|808|807|806|805|804|803|802|801|800|699|698|697|696|695|694|693|692|691|690|689|688|687|686|685|684|683|682|681|680|679|678|677|676|675|674|673|672|671|670|599|598|597|596|595|594|593|592|591|590|509|508|507|506|505|504|503|502|501|500|429|428|427|426|425|424|423|422|421|420|389|388|387|386|385|384|383|382|381|380|379|378|377|376|375|374|373|372|371|370|359|358|357|356|355|354|353|352|351|350|299|298|297|296|295|294|293|292|291|290|289|288|287|286|285|284|283|282|281|280|269|268|267|266|265|264|263|262|261|260|259|258|257|256|255|254|253|252|251|250|249|248|247|246|245|244|243|242|241|240|239|238|237|236|235|234|233|232|231|230|229|228|227|226|225|224|223|222|221|220|219|218|217|216|215|214|213|212|211|210|98|95|94|93|92|91|90|86|84|82|81|66|65|64|63|62|61|60|58|57|56|55|54|53|52|51|49|48|47|46|45|44|43|41|40|39|36|34|33|32|31|30|27|20|7|1|\-]*)\s([0-9]+)/
```